# Mysql - Using cursor in Stored Function

Tags: mysql, cursor, stored-functions

I am trying to pass a username and get level of the user if the username matches the username of row.

Here is the code I have written so far.

> DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION Get_Userlevel(ahash varchar) RETURNS INT
>   BEGIN DECLARE lvl,vlevel INT(10); DECLARE v_username varchar(50);
>
> DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT level,username FROM users;
>
> OPEN user_cursor;
>
> get_level : LOOP
>
> FETCH next into vlevel,v_username;
>
> IF v_username = ahash THEN  SET lvl = vlevel;  LEAVE get_level; END
>   IF;
>
> END LOOP get_level;
>
> CLOSE user_cursor;
>
> RETURN (lvl); END//

I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Why do you need a cursor? With a simple query you can get what you need.

Comment: @wchiquito I need to do it with cursor because this is just a try on how to do it. I am using cursor for first time. I have more complex thing to do with it.